# Vue JS: Sending an axios post data from an object

Tags: vue.js, axios

I need to set my JSON to variable because I am using it in 2 places, the

```
let data = {
         "test": "hello",
         "test2": "hello2
    }
    axios.post('/route', {
       data
    })
    .then((response) => {
        this.$emit('anotherFunction', data);
    })
```

I get a `400` back and then when I inspect the network request, the payload is: `"{data: {"test": "hello", "test2": "hello2"}}"` which makes sense but how can I have the JSON without the `data` part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `data` like this:

```
let data = {
         "test": "hello",
         "test2": "hello2
}
axios.post('/route', data)
.then((response) => {
        this.$emit('anotherFunction', data);
})
```

Comment: ooh I was putting it directly in `{ } `.   Thanks !